# CakePHP link without href attribute

Tags: html, cakephp, hyperlink, href, html-helper

Is it possible to create a CakePHP link using HtmlHelper without href attribute?

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Enter'); ?>
```

Will output:

```
<a href="">Enter</a>
```

What I want is this:

```
<a>Enter</a>
```

Comment: without href `<a></a>` tag display undeline  text.to achieve this you can use label with css to show underline.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try tag() rather than link()

```
echo $this->Html->tag('a', 'Enter');
```

In HtmlHelper link() automatically assigns the href tag

So you can create and king of Html tag by using

```
$this->Html->tag('Tag Name');
```